# Creating a list containing 30k numbers

Tags: python

So I am trying to compare the speeds of sorting a list.  I wrote my own insertion sort function and I am comparing it with pythons built in sorting method.  I now am trying to create a list that randomly generates like 30,000 or whatever numbers.  Then I'm going to use a for loop to start with a list of like 1000 numbers and increment it by 1000 until I reach 30k.  Here is what I have so far, I am having trouble with using the for loop to create a list of 30k digits.

```
    import time
    import random



def InsertionSort(A):
    for i in range(1,len(A),1):
        target = A[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >=0 and target < A[j]:
            A[j+1] = A[j]
            j = j - 1
        A[j+1] = target
    return A

def TimSort(A):
    A.sort()

    return A
```

Comment: What problems are you having with the `for` loop? The code you posted is only your sorting functions. Maybe you could post your attempt at the `for` loop?

Comment: sure thing, give me a second and I'll edit it in, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to generate N random numbers, you could use:

```
import random
random_numbers = [ random.random() for _ in xrange(N) ]
```

The `random` module also has methods like `randint` for returning a random integer. Consult its documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to seed a random list of digits, you didn't specify a length, so I just picked 65535.

```
import random

nums = range(65535)     # Original list of 65535 digits
random.shuffle(nums)    # Now they're in random order
first30k = nums[:30000] # 30,000 random digits from 0-65535 in random order
```

Comment: Probably enough for what the OP needs, but this list isn't truly random because the the list of numbers you get this way doesn't contain repeats.

Comment: You know, I thought of that at first and then forgot midway through.